# Adjust columns as per jqGrid width

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have jqGrid with `shrinkToFit: false` and `autowidth: true` and have 5 columns inside the grid.

It looks perfect unless one more column is added in the grid i.e. if there are 6 columns, then scroll bar appears at the bottom of the Grid.

Is there any way that whatever is the number of columns, all columns should get fit inside the grid without displaying scrollbar?

I tried giving hard-coded width to columns but I want some solution which will work for any number of columns.

My JQGrid code looks as follows

```
$("#grid1").jqGrid({
        colModel: [
            { name: "name", label: "Client", width: 53 },
            { name: "name", label: "Client1", width: 53 },
            { name: "name", label: "Client2", width: 53 },
            { name: "name", label: "Client3", width: 53 },
            { name: "invdate", label: "Date", width: 75, align: "center", sorttype: "date",
             formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y" } },
            { name: "amount", label: "Amount", width: 65, template: "number" },
            { name: "tax", label: "Tax", width: 41, template: "number" },
            { name: "total", label: "Total", width: 51, template: "number" },
            { name: "closed", label: "Closed", width: 59, template: "booleanCheckboxFa", firstsortorder: "desc" },
            { name: "ship_via", label: "Shipped via", width: 87, align: "center", formatter: "select",
             formatoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;DH:DHL", defaultValue: "DH" } }
        ],
        data: [
            { id: "10",  invdate: "2015-10-01", name: "test",   amount: "" },
            { id: "20",  invdate: "2015-09-01", name: "test2",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
            { id: "30",  invdate: "2015-09-01", name: "test3",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
            { id: "40",  invdate: "2015-10-04", name: "test4",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
            { id: "50",  invdate: "2015-10-31", name: "test5",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
            { id: "60",  invdate: "2015-09-06", name: "test6",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
            { id: "70",  invdate: "2015-10-04", name: "test7",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
            { id: "80",  invdate: "2015-10-03", name: "test8",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
            { id: "90",  invdate: "2015-09-01", name: "test9",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
            { id: "100", invdate: "2015-09-08", name: "test10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
            { id: "110", invdate: "2015-09-08", name: "test11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
            { id: "120", invdate: "2015-09-10", name: "test12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" }
        ],
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        rownumbers: true,
        sortname: "invdate",
        sortorder: "desc",
        autowidth: true,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        caption: "The grid, which uses predefined formatters and templates"
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is the screenshot for it.

[JQGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4KBc.png)

Here I don't want scrollbars but all columns should get fit inside the grid

Comment: can you please share what you have tried sofar? or your jqgrid code

Comment: @jigneshpatel Please see my updated question. I have added JSFiddle

Comment: check my answer bellow. i have added one extra column

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, remove width property from all columns and set `shrinkToFit: true, and autowidth: true`.

Please check this fiddle

[JQGrid](https://jsfiddle.net/4ga1ekh3/65/)

When you set `shrinkToFit: true, and autowidth: true` then grid will take full width same as it's parent element. in example i added table under one div and that div has `500` width then grid will use `500px`

Comment: But in this case, if any new column is added, then all columns are not visible. I am looking for solution that all columns should get fit inside the grid (without displaying scrollbars), whatever is the number of columns.

Comment: it's not possible because there is grid's width limit and if you try to add 10 columns and grid width is about 500 px then no column will be fit.

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted but setting shrinkToFit: true is increasing the width of parent element as well i.e. parent size is increasing as per Grids width. Can't we do it with shrinkToFit: false?

Comment: @Aparna you can set width of your parent element. as i alredy mentioned in comment and also in jsfiddle i already set parent element width. you can set parent element width using bootstrap class or fixed width

Comment: Its not working for me. Even If I set parent <div> width, Grid is taking full page width and then parent s width is also increasing.

Comment: @Aparna can you please share your parent div css?

Comment: @Aparna check fiddle mentioned in my answer. and change width of parent div of table it will work.

Comment: I used the same parent as provided in fiddle

Comment: I solved this by removing autowidth: true and giving the width manually. The answer is updated.